# jquery remove specific div without id

Tags: jquery, html

I need to remove with jquery one div with class name 'form-group', the third 'form-group' div in my form.

Problem is there are several divs with the same class.

```
<div class="form-group header-group-0" id="form-group-ordersdetail">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="panel-form-ordersdetail" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Orders Detail
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Formulaire</div>
                                <div class="panel-body child-form-area">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        This div is to remove
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Would appreciate your expertise.

Thank you in advance, cheers, Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `nth-child(3)` psuedo-selector to select the third `.form-group` in its container:

```js
$('.form-group:nth-child(3)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group header-group-0" id="form-group-ordersdetail">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="panel-form-ordersdetail" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Orders Detail
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Formulaire</div>
              <div class="panel-body child-form-area">
                <div class="form-group">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  This div is to remove
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note that there's absolutely no need to include a big library like jQuery for something this simple, you can achieve it very easily with vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelector('.form-group:nth-child(3)').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks both of you  ! It is working as expected. 'CertainPerformance' proposal is wise since it spare resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq(n)` method for `form-group` divs to remove your desired div. See below code snippet

**[jQuery eq(n) API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

```js
$(function(){
  $("#panel-form-ordersdetail .panel-body.child-form-area .form-group:eq(2)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group header-group-0" id="form-group-ordersdetail">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="panel-form-ordersdetail" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Orders Detail
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Formulaire</div>
                                <div class="panel-body child-form-area">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        This div is to remove
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
```